# gmap inside div 100% height 100% width not working

Tags: css

I am trying to make a div with google map same as on airbnb page. Div's position with google map inside of it is fixed and gmap div's height and width are 100% and it seems when I open the page that it is that way, but the google logo on the bottom is not showing, even though when I inspect the element it doesnt show that it goes outside of the div.

```
#gmap {height:100%;
width:100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;}

.container {position: relative;
display: table;
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
width:100%;}

.container > div {
vertical-align: top;}

.map {position: fixed;
top: 70px;
right: 0;
min-height: 100%;
margin-right: 0px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99;
overflow: auto;}
```

HTML code `

```
    <div id="content">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-2">
         @section('leftsidebar')
                    @include('layouts.pages.leftsidebar')
                @show
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"
            <section class="content">
                @section('content')
                    @yield('content')
                @show
            </section><!-- /.content -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 map">
          <div id="gmap">       
          </div><!--/#gmap-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- ./wrapper -->`
```

Comment: Try adding: `html, body { height: 100%; }` ... Since you're using percentage heights, all parent elements, all the way up to the root element, must have a specified height.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it didn't help unfortunatly

Comment: If you can post all the relevant code or a demo (jsfiddle.net) we could look into it further.